# Animate sticky nav on scroll issue when scroll amount is small

Tags: css, css-animations, sticky

While creating a sticky navbar that should be animated on scroll reducing its height I notice a strange bug.

When scroll small (for example only one tap on down arrow key), the nav is bouncing because the script seems to return 0 for scroll.

Here is the code :

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollDiv = document.getElementById('dojo-nav');
  if (window.scrollY > 0) {
    scrollDiv.style.height = '50px';
  } else {
    scrollDiv.style.height = '200px';
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#dojo-nav {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="dojo-nav" style="position:sticky;top:0px;background: violet;height: 200px;"></div>
<div style="height:50vh;background-color: cyan;"></div>
<div style="height:100vh;background-color: orange;"></div>
```

Is there anybody who can solved this issue without setting position fixed and navbar spacer or same height ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sticky` doesn't work here because `window.scrollY` changes on the sticky DIV's height changes.

With `fixed` `window.scrollY` is stable thus no the jittering.

Also you don't need to set styles in JS, use a CSS variable to change CSS rule values dynamically:

```js
 window.onscroll = () => document.body.classList.toggle('collapsed-nav', window.scrollY > 0);
```

```css
body {
  --navbar-height: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body.collapsed-nav{
  --navbar-height: 50px;
}

#dojo-nav {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  background: violet;
  height: var(--navbar-height);
}

#content {
  padding-top: var(--navbar-height);  
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#footer {
  height:100vh;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="dojo-nav"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i was hoping to solve it with sticky but i think i should go back to good old fixed :-D

Comment: I'm curious, why the scroll height is changing with sticky ?

Comment: @AndreaTesta it changes with my fixed approach too. the problem that with sticky when the sticky changes its height , the window.scrollY is changing! too! with the fixed window.scrollY is stable so no the jittering.

Comment: @AndreaTesta corrected my answer

Comment: PS: avoid using on* handlers like `window.onscroll`. All it takes is to follow that bad practice, introduce another `window.onscroll` somewhere else in your code and see the previous one go bananas. Always (besides when i.e: creating brand new elements from in-memory) — use `addEventListener`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i know about that, the question is about css, so i don't care about JS here except changing the manual style manipulation to toggling a class

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev it was more of a comment for OP (but yes, too often I expect answers to be of full quality). Good answer nevertheless.